# load data to div content failed in jsp

Tags: jquery, html, jsp

I had followin code which is suppose to display the loaded data in div with id = bodyContainer but is redirecting to url...

```
function viewCategory() {

$.get('/management/Category', function(data){ //received data 

$('#bodyContainer').html(data); //doesnt show in bodycontainer instead redirects to get method url

}); }

</script>

    <body>
<table class="table">

<tr>
<td><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/assetCategory" onclick="viewCategory()"> View Category</a>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<div class="col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10" id="bodyContainer" >Welcome </div>
```

Comment: What do you want to do when click on `anchor` link? You want to go to the path given in `href` or want to replace the div contents?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you have specified `href` for `a` tag and it will obviously redirect. If you want to `ajax` here, which seems to be, either you should prevent default action of `a` or just remove `href` value and replace with `#` or `javascript:void(0)`.

**Case 1**

```
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/assetCategory" class="getData"> View Category</a>
```

Bind `Event click` for this

```
$('a.getData').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); //will prevent from redirecting
    //Also you can use `$.load` instead of `get`
    $('#bodyContainer').load('/management/Category', function(data){ 
          //Anything to execute after load is complete
    }); 
});
```

**Case 2**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="viewCategory()">
```

You can just use your `function` or  remove `onlick` and bind it with `jquery` as shown in **Case 1**

```
function viewCategory(){
    //It will be a good option if you use $.load instead of $.get in this scenario
    $('#bodyContainer').load('/management/Category', function(data){ 
          //Anything to execute after load is complete
    });
}
```

Comment: thank you the second case resolved the problem it was  an issue with href